# XML XSLT Wrap specific elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to change this XML with XSLT transformation but it doesn't seem I can manage it. The XML I want to change is this:

```
<GOOITEGDS>
<GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
<NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
<ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
<PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
<ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
<StaValAmoGDI1>12.28</StaValAmoGDI1>
<PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
<PreDocRefAR26>3672</PreDocRefAR26>
<PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
<DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
<DocRefDC23>2712</DocRefDC23>
<DocTypDC21>Y900</DocTypDC21>
<DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
<DocTypDC21>Y922</DocTypDC21>
<DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
<ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
<TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
<TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
<TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
<NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
</GOOITEGDS>
```

and I'd like with XSLT to have the following result wrapping 3 specific elements in another node

```
    <GOOITEGDS>
    <GroMasGDS46>0.046</GroMasGDS46>
    <NetMasGDS48>0.01</NetMasGDS48>
    <ProReqGDI1>10</ProReqGDI1>
    <PreProGDI1>00</PreProGDI1>
    <ComNatProGIM1>000</ComNatProGIM1>
    <StaValAmoGDI1>12.28</StaValAmoGDI1>
<PREADMREFAR2>
    <PreDocTypAR21>380</PreDocTypAR21>
    <PreDocRefAR26>3672</PreDocRefAR26>
    <PreDocCatPREADMREF21>Z</PreDocCatPREADMREF21>
</PREADMREFAR2>
    <DocTypDC21>N380</DocTypDC21>
    <DocRefDC23>2712</DocRefDC23>
    <DocTypDC21>Y900</DocTypDC21>
    <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
    <DocTypDC21>Y922</DocTypDC21>
    <DocRefDC23>-</DocRefDC23>
    <ComNomCMD1>71171900</ComNomCMD1>
    <TARCodCMD1>00</TARCodCMD1>
    <TARFirAddCodCMD1>0000</TARFirAddCodCMD1>
    <TARSecAddCodCMD1>0000</TARSecAddCodCMD1>
    <NAtAddCodCMD1>0000</NAtAddCodCMD1>
    </GOOITEGDS>
```

I have tried the following but it wraps each element of the three separately.

```
  <xsl:template match="PreDocTypAR21|PreDocRefAR26|PreDocCatPREADMREF21">
   <PREADMREFAR2>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </PREADMREFAR2>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks a lot, Nikos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the order of the nodes is known and constant, you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/GOOITEGDS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocTypAR21/preceding-sibling::*"/>
        <PREADMREFAR2>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocTypAR21 | PreDocRefAR26 | PreDocCatPREADMREF21"/>
        </PREADMREFAR2>
        <xsl:copy-of select="PreDocCatPREADMREF21/following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes the order of the nodes is constant. I tried that but it doesn't seem to change the file. It doesn't add the <PREADMREFAR2> anywhere in the XML.

Comment: It works fine. I just removed the / from /GOOITEGDS. Maybe because I have multiple nodes of  <GOOITEGDS></GOOITEGDS> in the XML. Thanks a lot for your help! I was trying to find a solution hours now!!