# How to wrap a matching element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am tring to add a `<fo:block-container>` wrapper element to any matching `<table>` element using xslt. The `<fo:block-container>` need to use the same `width` attribuate value as `<table>`

An example source would be like

```
<table width="654px">
 --contents
</table>
```

The desired outcome would be like

```
<fo:block-container width="654px">
  <fo:table width="654px">
     --contents
  </fo:table>
</fo:block-container>
```

Some similar posts I have seen so far are adding the new element inside the "matching" element - `<table>` in this case, like this [XML XSLT Wrap specific elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728818/xml-xslt-wrap-specific-elements). But I want to wrap the whole matching element using a wrapper element I specify.

Comment: @Frostless Please do not edit OP's code - you don't know what ti looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="table">
    <fo:block-container width="{@width}">
        <fo:table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block-container>
</xsl:template>
```

This assumes you have other templates to process the table's nodes - see an example here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ncntCSh/1

Comment: The concept is correct and in my case I just remove `xsl:copy-of` and use my existing template and it worked

Comment: Yes, I removed `xsl:copy-of` as soon as you modified your expected output from `table` to `fo:table`.